# How to determine why a page is banned by Google

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing

There is a website which is correctly indexed by Google. And there is a page which was correctly indexed initially but after a couple of week was removed from the Google index. Most probably a page was banned. The content of this page had not changed during this time.

We didn't use any forbidden methods for promotion of this page. I looked for possible reasons (e.g. www.bigoakinc.com/seo-articles/banned-by-google.php) and didn't found any explicit mistakes.

Could you advise what we can do to return page to the index? The problem page is http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/

Comment: Are you sure it's not indexed? I see tons of pages within that directory that are indexed. Maybe it just doesn't rank well and that's why you can't find it?

Comment: It looks to me like many pages in that folder are indexed, but the folder/page itself is not.  cache:http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library returns nothing.

Comment: Occasionally, when Google rolls out an algorithm update, they deindex some pages and it takes a few weeks for them to get reindexed. Though I can't imagine why the adjacent pages would be indexed while this one isn't, especially as it's being linked to from all the other pages.

Answer (score 6):

Create a Webmasters Account from Google, here http://www.google.com/webmasters/.

Once you have an account you can attach it to the website in question by putting a file into the root folder of your site.  Google will then recognize that you as the owner of the Webmaster account also own/control the site in question.

Once you have done this Google will report to that account any reasons why your site is banned whether is is right now or in the future.  You can also use that account to ask Google if there is issues.

Note, once you know that there is an issue in your site and you have resolved it, you can Request Google to Reconsider your site through the Webmasters tool. This is an automated feature so no one will respond do you reconsideration request.

Google's webmaster tools also have a lot of other benefits and is free.  Specifically, it tells you what sites & pages link to your site and how many searches and at what position your site was returned for those searches.

Comment: I don't think Google ever tells you the reasons. "Unfortunately, we can't reply individually to reconsideration requests."  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/reconsideration.

Comment: @Alex - Correct.  They don't reply to your reconsideration.  They do usually give you an automated reason as to why.  One of our hosting companies was hacked a while back and Google Webmaster had a message that the site had been removed from SERP because of a virus link in the page and named the link.  We had to do some work ourselves but that did end up leading to the solving the problem.  It is also a way to be proactive in the future.

Comment: @Alex_Black - Getting *anything* from the source is better than a guess from anyone else... base guesses off of what little info Google provides if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I use Google Webmaster Tools, but did not see anything suspicious there. Now I've sent reconsideration request and will wait to some feedback.

Comment: I once submitted a reconsideration request to google, and all their response said was "we've received your request".  It didn't acknowledge there was a problem, or a solution, or that they did or didn't do anything. :)

Comment: @Alex: Right when you submit a reconsideration you don't get anything.  But if you have a webmasters account and your site gets infected they do send you an automate message stating that your site has an issue.  It is up to you to fix it and then request reconsideration.

Answer (score 1):

To determine your website banned by Google, you should check your log files or check with Google analytics report.

If your staff has advanced technical skill, then they can easily find the problems by reviewing log files.

If your staff doesn’t have the advanced technical skill, it is better that you can check the web analytics reports.

If you find a significant drop in Google crawling, then it means that your site has been banned or Google has difficulty crawling your site due to technical reasons.
You can also find with the index count method.

Type site:yourdomain.com

If your site is included in the Google index, it has not been banned. However, if your site has an index count of zero, it is a strong indication that your site might be banned.

Similarly you can check with link count method.

Type link:www.yourdomain.com

If there are links to your site in the Google index, your site has not been banned. If your site has a link count of zero, it is a strong indication that your site might be banned.

If everything is fine, then find some problems that are in robots.txt file, URL structure, server redirection, site navigation, cross-linking or any password protection issue.

You can also change the web content if your website is banned by Google panda or can request Google to remove the poor backlink using the Google disavow tool if banned by the Google penguin update.